# Do ISPs strip or modify QoS/DSCP headers to and from the edge?

Tags: networking, qos

If I mark a packet at a edge location with DSCP, does anyone know if ISPS (or in a general sense, middleboxes) strip or modify the DSCP header on UDP packets before they reach another edge location?  Most interesting to me is residential to residential.

**EDIT:**  I don't expect the ISP to honor them (*Netflix, why didn't you just mark your packets? /sarcasm*); I just hope the packets remain unmodified from edge-to-edge.

I'd be interested in answers such as:

- I've seen it before, but I have no idea how widespread it is
- It happens a large percentage (> 10%)
- It does not happen much (< 10%)
- Rare (< %1)

I know this question is awfully hard to answer unless you have tried to do this, but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible to speak authoritatively on, but in my experience, the *vast* majority of ISPs ignore QoS and DSCP headers, and with good reason. If they respected those headers, they would quickly become meaningless as everyone just starts to mark *all* their packets as EF or AF or somesuch.

The only way to have true end-to-end QoS is to run the entire network yourself.

Comment: I expect them to ignore them.  I'm just hoping they are preserved in transit...  but let me update my question to make that clear.